# Unable to attach role to a user, when creating an account using Jetstream - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to attach a role and update the `registered_at` field in the `invitations` table through the Jetstream authentication controller itself, located at `App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser`. I want to perform the said above function when the user creates an account.

The below code is performing the function as I wanted, It's successfully updating the `registered_at` field, and attaching the role as well, but is not successfully redirecting to the dashboard.

**Error**

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\2020\vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController.php on line 56

**App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php - *Updated Code***

```
public function create(array $input) {
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => $this - > passwordRules(),
    ]) - > validate();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
    ]);

    $user - > roles() - > sync('3');
    $invitation = Invitation::where('email', $user - > email) - > firstOrFail();
    $invitation - > registered_at = $user - > created_at;
    $invitation - > save();
}
```

**App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php - *Original Code***

```
public function create(array $input) {
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => $this - > passwordRules(),
    ]) - > validate();

    return User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the $user from the method

```php
public function create(array $input) {
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => $this - > passwordRules(),
    ]) - > validate();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
    ]);

    $user - > roles() - > sync('3');
    $invitation = Invitation::where('email', $user - > email) - > firstOrFail();
    $invitation - > registered_at = $user - > created_at;
    $invitation - > save();

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original code a user is returned,. In my version there is no return statement. JetStream/Fortify expects a user instance to be returned from that method.

Just had to add this, in the end.

```
return $user;
```